# Ubuntu 14.10 with Xubuntu Alt_L key doesn't act like Alt_R

Tags: ubuntu, key-bindings, xubuntu

I can't cycle apps or change tabs using the left Alt in Xubuntu 14.10.  I've tried different mappings and disabling the compose key to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like user error.  I had inadvertently mapped Alt_L to switching to a particular workspace.